# Knockout Template in foreach access specific template item

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js, indexing, foreach

I am populating a list of survey questions. On click of a survey question, a modal with graphs of the results pop up. To create my list I am using a knockout template as I need the `afterRender` function.

Here's my markup:

```
<div id="priorityMenuW" class="priorityMenuW shadow">
    <div class="menuHeader">Select a Survey Question:</div>
    <div id="priorityMenu" data-bind="foreach:questionTypes">
        <div class="menucategory menuItem" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bind="text:CategoryName, attr:{title:CategoryName}"></div>
        <div class="menuitem" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bind="foreach:$root.questions">
            <!-- ko if: CategoryName == $parent.CategoryName-->
            <div data-bind='template: { name: "question-template",
                                        data:$root.questions,
                                        afterRender: $root.storeQuestionIdOrder }'>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my template:

```
<code><script type="text/html" id="question-template">

<div class="menuItem" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bind="html:'&bull; '+ $parent.QuestionText, attr:{title:$parent.QuestionText}, css: {'itemSelected' : $root.isPriorityActive($data)}, click: function($data,event){$root.questionChoice($data,event)}"></div></script></code>
```

My problem is that by sending `$data` to the function `questionChoice`, I am receiving an array of all of the templated objects. How can I access the specific object clicked on? I was thinking maybe `$data[$index]`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use `$data[$index]`, remember that `$index` is an observable and needs to be evaluated:

`$data[$index()]`

Comment: Thank you sir. I suppose the frustration set in well enough to cause me to look over the simplest of errors.